# La hora no me guarda correctamente

Tags: php, html, sintaxis, error404

lo que sucede es que estoy tratando de guardar la hora de la siguiente manera:

```
$hoy = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

El día me lo guarda correctamente, mientras que la hora me la guarda mal, ya que un ejemplo que realice, en mi computadora dice que son las 07:36 a.m mientras que en el formulario (que esta conectado con PHP y guardando en PhpMyAdmin) me guarda un horario con ventaja de 5 horas...

Y no he podido arreglarlo...

Si me colaboran muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], es muy importante que leas [ask], [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/107347), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878/107347) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes definir la zona horaria:

```
    // Definir la zona horaria
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota");
    $hoy = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ya por fin me dio...

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que poner el Timezone. Te está capturando la hora de tu servidor.

Puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
ini_set('date.timezone','Europe/Madrid'); 
$hoy = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```